# Trigger window resize event with dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, c3

I would like to find a way to trigger the **window resize event** (the one fired when you resize the window of your browser) using `Dojo`. It will allow me to resize my `C3` Charts.

I found the module `on` allowing to listen and trigger custom events with the function `emit`, so here is what I tried :

```
on.emit(win, 'resize', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
```

Where `win` is the `dojo/_base/window` module that I tried to use as the source of the fired event. I also tried this :

```
on.emit(win.body(), 'resize', {bubbles: true,cancelable: true});
```

But nothing is working, my charts are not receiving the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the plain window object:

```
on(window, 'resize', function() { console.log('resize!')});
on.emit(window, 'resize', {bubbles: true,cancelable: true})
```

Comment: Thanks, your advice helped me. ...but anyway I still wondering which native Dojo object should be used in such case??

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is no native dojo object that you could use instead of `window`. You want to interact with the browser window, thus you use `window` keyword. Dojo does not redefine standard objects available in all browsers.

Comment: ...ah, I thought Dojo has some wrappers for global objects... Ok, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/Viewport"
], function(declare, Viewport) {

    return declare("Som", [Viewport], {
        onClick: function(){
            Viewport.emit("resize");
        }
    });

});
```